# JQuery get() results conversion

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I am trying to get data from an outside domain that I do not have access to. My end goal is to be able to display it as a table, or later as a dynamic chart. The problem is that the domain that I am requesting information from only allows for either a return datatype of "script", or "JSONP". Other datatTypes give me the **"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."** error. The file that I need access to is a .csv file. I tried using the following code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#test").click(function(){
        var url = "outsidedomain.com";
              $.get( url, function (data) {
                  var dataStr = new String(data);
                  dataToTable(dataStr);
              }, "script");
       });
   });
```

When I use the above code, I receive a **"Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/csv"** warning, and a **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"** error. How do I get and manipulate the data in the .csv file using jquery under these circumstances?

Comment: Can you mark the line where the error appears?